BalenaEtcher fails to write to USB
I downloaded the file  "ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64" and tried to use it with BalenaEtcher.
it writes the USB and after the Validate there is an error. the USB drive appears then twice and the description is "it is not formatted - please format" Formatting the USB again doesn't work because of the message "the drive is protected".
I downloaded a second image from a mirror and tried again but got the same result.

Try it with another USB or if you have a switch for write protection turn it off.

USB thumb/flash drives are made to cost, ie. a cheap consumable item, and risk failure when written to (its not the whole device that fails, but part of the memory which can no longer store data correctly). Your details fit a failed thumb-drive as I read it.

I tried it now with RUFUS and it worked fine - thanks for the help
